# Blending tool orientation WTF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I am trying to make the blend tool have an array of lines go around a circle and all point perfectly into the middle.

Every single time I change orientation in the blend tool options, it changes to a 45 degree angle spread.

I want it to **look like the circle on the left** but when I try I can only get the circle on the right.

[image]

Comment: This is kind of nerdy, but I don't like the blend tool because I like my numbers to be precise. I divide 360 into the number of instances I want, then use a transform effect to rotate and copy the element. A vector point in the middle, grouped will give you precise control over the point of rotation.

Comment: I like precision too, but the problem with the transform tool is that is doesn't give me control of the rotation point. If I create a box and a triangle and I wanted 20 triangles around the box, I would click on the centre of the box with the rotation tool, and when I click on transform-rotate, the centre point goes to a default place of the centre between both objects selected.

Comment: You just create an empty vector at the center point, group that with the triangle and transform that object. In your example, the box should be outside of the effect. Unless I'm missing something, that always worked for me (when I couldn't pull it off with the shape alone).

Comment: @DavidO use rotate tool and alt + click the point! Then it does not move

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Scissors Tool** and click on an anchor for the circle path to "open" the path. That will change how the blend is treated on that spine.

[image]

[image]

You need to cut the circle spine **before** you've changed the orientation.

You failed to mention that you didn't create the first image you posted and that you were trying to *get* to that image. I kind of thought you started with the left image and any change was resulting in the right image. It took a moment to figure out you were working from scratch, not altering the left image.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I knew it was easy. I know what I was doing. I was change the orientation BEFORE the cut. I need to make sure to cut first BEFORE orientation changes.

Comment: @DavidO please make an [edit] to your question to address that.  There is nothing indicating your comment in the question so how can we best help you if we don't know everything?

Comment: You are correct David. I edited this answer.